# Find sorted version of list

Tags: python, list, sorting, data-science

I have a list of tags "list_a" and a second bigger list with tags and a score "list_b". I would like to find the sorted version of list_a based on the score of the tags in list_b. The goal is the print a number of signals but sorted based on their respective scores. Currently i print them like this:

```
    plot_tags = {
        'Tag_x': 1,
        'Tag_y': 2,
        'Tag_z': 3,
    }

 ax[1].set_ylabel('Tag_x')
 ax[2].set_ylabel('Tag_y')
 ax[3].set_ylabel('Tag_z')
```

However i want to plot them dynamically based on the score plot_tags have from list_b

```
list_b
tag
Tag_c   1.637486
Tag_a  -1.397149
Tag_v   1.390255
Tag_b  -1.248466
Tag_f  -1.243615
                      ...
```

P.S. list_a contains elements that list_b doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn `list_b` into a dictionary (`dict_b`) and then use a costume sorting function -

```
sorted_list_a = sorted(list_a, key = lambda x: dict_b.get(x, 0))
```

Comment: The problem is that list_a contains elements that list_b doesn't so that gives an error. Can i give a score of 0 somehow in those cases?

Comment: I added 0 as a default value in order to fix this problem